# Store CI query into an array?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've got the following function in a model, however it keep returning:

Message: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

And I for the life of me can't figure out why.

```
    function getNames() {
    $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM Device_tbl ORDER BY Manufacturer");   
    $dev = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1))
        {
            $manu =  $row['Manufacturer'];
            $mod = $row['Model'];
            $dev[] = $manu.' '.$mod;
        }
    return $dev->result();
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer for CodeIgniter is:

```
    $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table");  

    foreach($query1->result_array() as $row)
        {
            $manu =  $row['column1'];
            $mod = $row['column2'];
            echo $manu.' '.$mod;
        }
    return $query1->result();
```

Comment: it appears then that you didn't actually connect to the database.       http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: or there could be an error with your query, but I don't see you doing any debugging.

Comment: Looks like he's mixing a CodeIgniter query with a mysql query.

Comment: On a side note: If `$dev === array()`, then you can't do `$dev->result();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you're mixing CodeIgniter database methods with built in PHP database methods. `mysql_fetch_array` expects a resource, not a CI query object.

Check out the [docs](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html) on fetching results.

Comment: OK so I got that working, however my array from $query1 contains everything rather than just the 2 columns as I specified?

Comment: You specify which columns it returns within the query.  You have `SELECT * FROM` which will select all columns.

Comment: OK makes sense.  So i've sorted it out but I have several manufacturers of the same name and it only returns the first one of each

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, when you get a lot of data (lines) to process, you may want to use native php mysql functions like mysql_fetch_array to save memory (for best memory saving I prefer mysql_fetch_row). In this case you can use this :

```
try {

    $query = $this->db->query("SOME QUERY");


    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($query->result_id)) {

        /* ... */

    }

    $query->free_result(); //we talked about memory saving right ;-)
} catch(Exception $e) {
    /* ... */
}
```